# How do I selectively add 3rd select box or relabel & redirect to a 2nd select box?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a form where the 1st select box is required. Depending on the selection, a different table will be used as a source for the query to populate a 2nd select box. Then depending also on the 1st selection a 3rd select box may or may not be necessary. I have designed the form to initially show 3 select boxes, but the user would have to know to skip the 2nd select box in some cases. This is confusing at the least. As an example:
If None is selected for Company, then both the Cemetery & Section select boxes would have to shown (Section being dependent on Cemetery selected). If XYZ Company is selected, then only the Section select box would need to be seen / selected (as the Cemetery is Company specific):

```
<script>
function getCemetery(val) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get_cemetery.php",
    data:'company_name='+val,
    success: function(data){
        $("#cemetery-list").html(data);
    }
    });
}
```

Here is the code of the form:

```
<body>
<div class="frmDronpDown">
<div class="row">
<label>Company:</label><br/>
<select name="company" id="company-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getCemetery(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Company</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $company) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $company["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $company["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Cemetery:</label><br/>
<select name="cemetery" id="cemetery-list" class="demoInputBox" onChange="getSection(this.value);">
<option value="">Select Cemetery</option>
<?php
foreach($results as $cemetery) {
?>
<option value="<?php echo $cemetery["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $cemetery["name"]; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="row">
<label>Section:</label><br/>
<select name="section" id="section-list" class="demoInputBox">
<option value="">Select Section</option>
</select>
</div>


</div>
</body>
```

And here is the additional php code the is called within the script:

```
<?php
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["company_name"])) {
 if (($_POST["company_name"]<>"None") && ($_POST["company_name"]<>"Other")) {


 $sql="SELECT name, available  FROM compsections WHERE cname = '".$_POST["company_name"]."'"." ORDER by available desc;";
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error());
 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 $section = $row[0]; // best choice to use if auto fill

  $query="SELECT * FROM compsections WHERE cname = '".$_POST["company_name"]."'"." ORDER by available desc;";
  $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
 echo '<option value="">Select Section</option>';


 }else{

       $query ="SELECT * FROM cemeteries";
       $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
       echo '<option value="">Select Cemetery</option>';
 }

    foreach($results as $cemetery) {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $cemetery["name"]; ?>"><?php echo $cemetery["name"]." - ".$cemetery["available"]; ?></option>
<?php
    }

}
?>
```

Edit:
Thank you for telling me about .hide and .show. I have looked up examples and what I can find uses a button click. Would you show an example of using them in an php if..else?

Thank you in advance. 
Russ

Comment: Use jquery `.hide()` and `.show()` to hide the boxes you don't need  and show them when the corresponding selections are made.

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track. I ended up using .slideup().

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
<script>
function wholesection() {

$( "#whole-section" ).slideUp( "fast", function() {
  });
}
</script>
```

AND

```
 echo '<script>',
     'wholesection();',
     '</script>'
;
```